# What is the most suitable descriptor to use for object detection?

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, haar-classifier, viola-jones, lbph-algorithm

I want to build an object detector for several objects (cat, flower and car) based on viola jones algorithm. We can use HOG, LBP and HAAR-like descriptors.
How we can know what is the most suitable descriptor according to each object?

Comment: You can know which one is best by trying them all out and seeing which one gives the best results.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? For these kinds of objects, Viola Jones detectors have.been surpassed by CNNs by a large margin.